# Periodically deleting expired records in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table that contains temporary data which uses a column to store the expiration date/time. What is the best approach to periodically clean out expired records in MVC3?

Comment: Sounds more like a job for a Windows Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, then I would highly recommend [Creating a Job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) in your Sql Server.  Any data changes that do not require user input, should be the job of the data store.  If down the road some other application needs the same data, you can be assured that the records will be *cleaned* even if the website is down for any reason.